# Customizing display of facets with Apache Solr Search

Tags: search

I am using Apache Solr, and Facet API for search.
I have configure Apache Solr with facet, and its working fine, but I want to change the  layout of faceted block displayed on the page.

Now it displays as on left side image.

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]

I want to display the same as in the right side image. I mean that, when I move over on any of the options, the right side there displays its related data in a small pop up.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please make sure you add what you've already tried to the question, this site isn't an appropriate place to ask for a full tutorial

Comment: hey Clive i am not asking full tutorial but i want to know how to customize my filters.